# Jar entry not found by running gradle generated jar

Tags: spring, rest, gradle, spring-boot

I've downloaded the source code (zip file) from the spring getting started guide: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Building the whole project within the folder "complete" was successful. Also running the generated jar file using Gradle (gradle run) was successful. But when I try to run it manually in the Windows command line with "java -jar build\libs\gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar" the startup process failed with the following error:

> 2014-06-25 14:17:22.414 ERROR 6864 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure during classpath scanning; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR
> entry /hello/ not found in D:\gs-rest-service-master\complete\build\libs\gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar

Apparently spring can not find the folder "hello" even though it is located within the jar (I've checked it with the command "jar -ft").

Comment: Maybe try `gradle run --debug` to see how gradle runs jar

Comment: The debug output is very unclear. In some lines the null pointer exception is displayed but also the message "Discarding resolve failure" in the line before. Which means these minor resolve errors are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say which version of Boot you're using, but it sounds like you've hit a [recently reported problem in 1.1.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1145) that's specific to Windows. You can either drop back to 1.1.1 or wait for 1.1.3 which, given the problems with 1.1.2 on Windows, should be available in the not too distant future.

Comment: Like you said the issue was caused by the mentioned incompatibility between boot release 1.1.2 and Windows. I just set the release 1.1.1 in the Gradel build file and it works fine. Thank you for the answer.